# Not able to get form data using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, forms, post

## i am trying to save body of post form in mongodb.

## Everytime i get this result only.

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("63f222995b85f79e258642c4"), __v: 0 }
```

## HTML form code

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <div class="item11 bg12">
        <input id="inph" type="text" class="in bg1" placeholder="Phone number, username or email address">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item11">
        <input id="inpass" type="text" class="in bg1" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item11">
        <button type="submit" id="btlog" class="in bg2">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## node js code

```
const credential=mongoose.Schema({username:String,password:String});const cr_den=mongoose.model('instagram_clone',credential);
```

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.render('index.pug');})
```

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{var data=new cr_den(req.body);data.save().then(()=>{console.log("response Noted..!!");console.log(data);}).catch(()=>{console.log('Failed To Save Data...!!!')})res.render('index.pug');})
```

The result should be

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("63f222995b85f79e258642c4"), username:"xyz",password:"xyz",__v: 0 }
```

Comment: `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Looks like you didn't read the second sentence of [the documentation for `req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)